# Can't download the custom package of foundation zurb

Tags: download, zurb-foundation

I changed the value of color and body's width. I clicked on download button as usual but it returned have no file "/tmp/...". I understand that the hosting didn't zip the file for me to download. Is there anybody got this problem from Foundation Zurb site?

I tried to do that many times but got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. In general this is not a normal question and can be closed. Please ask this at https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues next time.

See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11826 and https://github.com/foundation/node-foundation-customizer/pull/13